# How to add a window event listener (within a functional component) that calls back function received as props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on my first React web app and got stuck creating a Knob/dial component that will be re-used hundreds of times throughout the app.

The user interaction will be handled within 3 elements, the **Knob**, the Knob's **Parent**, and the **window** object.

The Knob will receive a **value** as props, and represent this **value** visually, and it will also allow user interaction, changing the **value** dynamically with click and drag mouse movements.

The user interaction expected is:

- < Knob onMouseDown > -> will set the **Knob** state "isChanging" to true, store mouse coordinates in the **Parent** state, and add 2 event listeners in the **window** object:

  - window.AddEventListener('onmousemove' -> if Knob state "isChanging" is true, calculate the new **value** (calling back a function passed as props to the **Knob**), and store it in the **Parent** state)
  - window.addEventListener('onmouseup' -> set Knob state "isChanging" to false)

The Knob will receive the **value** property dynamically (as part of the **Parent** state). I also wanna pass, as props  to the **Knob**, the callback functions that will handle the mouse movements.

The thing is that I'm having trouble getting the window events to work..
Although I find out that the onMouseDown callback is working fine (altering the Knob state, and the mouseAt state value in the **Parent**), nothing that is set in the window event listeners is being executed when I move the mouse after clicking down in the Knob.

atm the code is as follows

```
class Parent extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state={
         value: 10,
         min: 0,
         max: 100,
         mouseAt: null;
      }
   }

   calcValue = (operation) => {
      if(operation === 'increase') {
         // Increase logic here
         // Will sure have some call of this.setState({value: x})
      }
      if( operation === 'decrease') {
         // Decrease logic here
         // Will sure have some call of this.setState({value: x})
      }
   }

   onMouseMove = (e) => {
      if (e.clientY < this.state.mouseAt) {
         this.calcValue('increase');
      }
      if (e.clientY > this.state.mouseAt) {
         this.calcValue('decrease');
      }
      this.setState({mouseAt: e.clientY});
   };

   startMove = (e) => {
      this.setState({mouseAt: e.clientY});
   }

   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <Knob windowMouseMove={this.onMouseMove} startMove={this.startMove} value={this.state.value) min={this.state.min} max={this.state.max} radius={15}></Knob>
         </div>

      )
   }
}
```

and then in the Knob component:

```
function describeArc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle){
   // return svg path code
}

const Knob = (props) => {
   const [isChanging, setChangeState] = useState(false);

   useEffect(() => {
      if (isChanging) {
         window.addEventListener('onmousemove', props.windowMouseMove);
         window.addEventListener('onmouseup', stopMoving);              
      };               


      return () => {
         if (!isChanging) {
            window.removeEventListener('mousemove', props.windowMouseMove);
            window.removeEventListener('mouseup', stopMoving);
         }
      }
   }, [isChanging])


   const startMoving = (e) => {
      setChangeState(true);
      props.startMove(e);
      }


   const stopMoving = () => {
      setChangeState(false);
   }

   return (
      <svg onMouseDown={startMoving}>
         <path id="arc1" fill="none" stroke="446688" strokeWidth="5" 
            d={describeArc(27.5, 27.5, props.radius, -160, 160)}/>
         <path id="arc2" fill="none" stroke="#4169' strokeWidth="5" 
            d={decribeArc(27.5, 27.5, props.radius, radProps(props.value, props.min, props.max), 160)}/>
      </svg>
   )
}
```

I also have tried adding the window event listeners directly in the onMouseDown callback, but without success.
Tracking the state between callback calls, I found that the last callback being executed is the one in the body of useEffect, with "isChanging" set to true, even though no window event listener is being executed.

Any help on how to pull this off is appreciated.

Thanks.

[SOLVED] - The solution was simple, instead of `window.addEventListener`, I used `window.onmousemove = props.windowMouseMove`, and `window.onmouseup = stopMoving`, and before unmounting `window.onmousemove = null` and `window.onmouseup = null`.

Comment: any error messages in the browser developer console?

Comment: No error messages.

Comment: Have you tried removing the dependency array from your `useEffect()`?

Comment: Yes, I've tried. But the same problem persists. If I remove the dependency array, the code inside `useEffect()` still runs, but no callback in the window event listeners is executed. I'm gonna try to change the direct window object to some kind of element with the useRef hook and see if it works.